# do we need to implement encryption for keychainwrapper class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was using RNCrptor for encrypting the username and password. But client suggested to store username and password in Keychain wrapper item class. So i dont have any idea whether this wrapper class internally encrypting the username and password or not. If not then its a security threat. Please give some suggestion on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my question is not understandable then please let me know . I will elaborate more on this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the keychain is encrypted for you, as you can read about [in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html). It's not the most secure form, but good enough for basic usage. A question about the type of encryption has already been answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312871/what-encryption-algorithm-does-the-ios-keychain-use-to-protect-data).